# Chrome 40, CSS3 animations become broken overtime

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I'm experiencing a strange issue.

When I open Chrome 40 I get very CSS3 smooth animations. After some arbitrary number of animations or page reloads, animations start to decrease their FPS (i.e. *frames per second*) until they become absolutely broken (no animation).

If I reboot the machine, the issue is solved for some time until it happens again.

Furthermore, I've verified GPU acceleration is ok reviewing `chrome://gpu` status page, and it's everything ok excepting it warns about the following issue:

> Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process
>   sandbox

I've also tried this on Chromium 42 and it's not having the issue, but because I'm developing an Apache Cordova app and I'm using Apache Ripple to work on app's layout, I need also `--disable-web-security` flag on Chrome to enable cross-origin AJAX requests to get the same behavior than the actual app on Android, and Chromium 42 accepts the whole flag, but it has no effect, thus I still need to use Chrome.

Does anyone experienced this issue and has solved it?

#### Also...

I've also tried to update to Chrome 41 beta and I get the same issue...

Comment: This looks like an issue for the Chrome bug tracker.

Comment: @Pavlo I didn't know that, but since Chromium 42 works well, I guessed that the fix should be in future Chrome releases...